# A table consisting of mathematical expressions

Tags: tables

[image]

The following is my code, but it didn't work, do I miss some package? Please, give me advice and correct code. Thanks for your help!

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& x<0 & x=0 & x>0\\ \hline
y<0 & x^2-y^2 & x^2+y^2 & x^2-y^2\\ \hline
y=0 & x+y & x^2-y^2 & x^2+y^2 & x^2-y^2\\ \hline
y>0 & x^2+y^2 & x+y & x^2+y^2\\ \hline
y<0 & x^2-y^2 & x^2+y^2 & x^2-y^2
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc. You can use the `array` environment

Comment: You have to surround your cells by `$...$` as they are mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
    & x<0     & x=0     & x>0\\ \hline
y<0 & x^2-y^2 & x^2+y^2 & x^2-y^2\\ \hline
y=0 & x+y     & x^2-y^2 & x^2+y^2 \\ \hline
y>0 & x^2+y^2 & x+y     & x^2+y^2\\ \hline
y<0 & x^2-y^2 & x^2+y^2 & x^2-y^2 \\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

In this way you can get a kind sort of table in mathematical environment without and `$ $` as LaRiFaRi say.s For me is easier in this way.

Comment: you solved my problem perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: @Mao Now you can choose the best answer and vote it. Mico's solution is very nice and more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Given that virtually all of the table's contents should be in math mode, you should use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. You also need to remove the duplicate entry on the `y=0` line to make your code compilable.

In order to get a table that doesn't look too much like a bunch of jail cell windows, I'd like to suggest that you also remove all vertical bars as well as most `\hline`s, and use the macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` of the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package to obtain well-spaced lines to mark the header row and the end of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{cccc}
\toprule
& x<0 & x=0 & x>0\\
\midrule
y<0 & x^2-y^2 & x^2+y^2 & x^2-y^2 \\
y=0 & x+y     & x^2-y^2 & x^2+y^2 \\
y>0 & x^2+y^2 & x+y     & x^2+y^2 \\
y<0 & x^2-y^2 & x^2+y^2 & x^2-y^2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the table, you posted in the image. In your code, you had too many cells. The third row has three `&` specifiers. This can't work.

You have to put every cell in math-mode. For example with `$...$`. As you are just using math in the whole table, you can set the complete columns in math mode with help of the package `array`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$} >{$}c<{$} >{$}c<{$} >{$}c<{$}}
        \toprule
            & x<0     & x=0     & x>0     \\
        \cmidrule(l){2-4} % the (l) is optional. The screenshot shows a version without it
        y<0 & x^2-y^2 & x^2+y^2 & x^2-y^2 \\
        y=0 & x+y     & x^2-y^2 & x+y     \\
        y>0 & x^2+y^2 & x+y     & x^2+y^2 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to add more rows with text in it, you will have to write `\text{...}` in each cell and load the package `mathtools` for that purpose. You will have to decide for each table if you are having more math or more text and use or omit the `>{$}c<{$}` likewise.